# color wheel return value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an image of a color wheel that spins on touch. What I cannot figure out is how to determine which color it lands on when rotating stops. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I am a newbie so sample code helps. Ideas?

Please help.

Comment: Could you provide code and screenshots for what you’ve got so far? From your question I can’t quite visualize what you’re trying to do.

Comment: How you are making the image to spin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what angle the wheel stops at when it finishes rotating, right?

If your colors are evenly divided along your wheel you can use that to determine the offset from the starting position, which divided by the number of colors will tell you which color is at the top.  Offset this again if your wheel's position marker is not dead top.